# Scraping SpringBoot actuator/prometheus metrics endpoint in an Istio environment

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, prometheus, istio

I have developed a couple of microservices using SpringBoot, has exposed some custom metrics using Micrometer which are available at /actuator/prometheus endpoint. I tested the application locally with docker prometheus container with scrape config pointing to the endpoint and its showing the metrics.

Now I have deployed it into kubernetes in GKE (version 1.14.7-gke.23) with Istio (version 1.4.0) enabled using the demo profile. But the prometheus that comes with istio is not scraping the SpringBoot /actuator/prometheus endpoint. I took queues from this link "https://preliminary.istio.io/faq/metrics-and-logs/#prometheus-application-metrics" and added the annotations to the Deployments but to no avail.

Help requested on how to get this working... Thanks

Comment: you may have more info if you check the "targets" status from prometheus console, what is it saying for your springboot pods? An error 404 on the scrape target path or something different?

Comment: @Joel, Yes I had gone there but I didn't see my pods as targets. I looked at the kubernetes-pods section particularly, as I assumed it may appear there. It has only app=kiali & app=jaeger labelled pods but none of mine.. The envoy-stats section has my pods but the Endpoint has URl "http://10.40.1.15:15090/stats/prometheus"  but mine is at 8080/actuator/prometheus

Comment: They are probably falling into the 'kubernetes-pods-istio-secure' section, no? You can ignore the ones from envoy-stats, it's only for the proxy metrics, not your own ones. If you want to force scraper to fetch http instead of https, you can add the annotation `prometheus.io/scheme: "http"`

Comment: btw for information, once you get these metrics enabled, you'll get a springboot dashboard out of the box in kiali https://kiali.io/documentation/runtimes-monitoring/

Comment: I had given the prometheus annotations only for the Deployment resource, but now when I gave the same in the Service resource, I am able to see the metrics. Its appearing under the kubernetes-service-endpoints section though. Regarding Kiali, the Kiali console was showing my microservices before too without any problem.

Comment: Thanks for this question.@KrishnaKumar I too get the metrics in service end points and not in in kubernetes pods target.Is there any problem with the set up or have you faced any problem later?

Comment: @sachin Its been a while I have used it, but if I remember, I couldn't get it correctly then.